# LCM for combinations

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, lcm

Two integers **n** and **k**, both ranging in **100000** is given.

How do we calculate the LCM for **n*<sup>n-1</sup>C<sub>0</sub>**(multiplication of n and (n-1 choose 0)), **n*<sup>n-1</sup>C<sub>1</sub>**(multiplication of n and (n-1 choose 1)), **n*<sup>n-1</sup>C<sub>2</sub>**(multiplication of n and (n-1 choose 2)), .........., **n*<sup>n-1</sup>C<sub>k</sub>**(multiplication of n and (n-1 choose k)) in modulo **1000000007**.

I am simply finding all values and then calculating the modulo which have lot of problems when the numbers grows up.

How to calculate it efficiently ?

Comment: This question would be best asked on [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is it a coding contest ? Please provide link.

Comment: @MrSmith42 `How to calculate it efficiently ?`

Comment: @MrSmith42 I am just calculating each term and finding the lcm of those which is the naivest approach and requires a lot of time for larger terms.

Comment: I may have a solution but I would like to check it before. Do you have any links with the solution or a way to validate the result ?

Comment: @fjardon We may look upon it by using the brute force method, I guess?

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

1. It's easy to see that lcm(nx, ny) = n*lcm(x, y)
   So actually the problem reduced to calculating lcm for C coefficients.
2. Also it is easy to see that lcm(x/a, x/b) = x/gcd(a, b), where gcd is a greatest common divisor.

If you remember that n choose k = n!/k!(n-k)! these two steps reduces the problem to calculation of

gcd(0!n!, 1!(n-1)!, 2!(n-2)!, ..., k!(n-k)!)

and then dividing n*n! by this value.

gcd can be easily computed by [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). There's actually even easier approach:

gcd(i!(n-i)!, (i+1)!(n-i-1)!) = i!(n-i-1)!gcd(n-i, i+1)

(for the last gcd you still have to use Euclidean algorithm. but now it is easier).

3. You can actually do all of the computations in a ring modulo 1000000007. It means that you can take a remainder of 1000000007 after each multiplication/addition, it wouldn't affect the answer.
4. In the end you have two values:

x = n*n! mod 1000000007

y = gcd(0!n!, 1!(n-1)!, 2!(n-2)!, ..., k!(n-k)!) mod 1000000007

Instead of dividing these numbers, you can multiply x by z, such that

z*y = 1 modulo 1000000007

You can read more about why this works in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and how to find such z [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

5. You have to use 64-bit integers, because even product of two 1000000007-mod numbers doesn't fit into 32 bits. Alternatively, you can write your own mod-multiplication algorithm, which doesn't overflow 32-bit values (it is easy to do, if you know how to write multiplication algorithm and take my advice on calculation 1000000007 remainder after each step).

Comment: To find the `z` value such that `x*z=1` you can just do a modular exponentiation of `x` to the power `1000000007-1-1`

Comment: Yeah, it'd work, but there's a better approach: use Euclidean algorithm again. I added a link to the explaination.

Comment: For finding gcd(0!n!, 1!(n-1)!, 2!(n-2)!, ..., k!(n-k)!), we will be calculating gcd of numbers pairwise by the relation gcd(i!(n-i)!, (i+1)!(n-i-1)!) = i!(n-i-1)!gcd(n-i, i+1) and then calculating gcd for all those answers. Correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: MetaD, yes, this should work.